# Are SLDS icons available natively in LEX?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, slds, svg-icon

According to [this](http://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/#unmanaged) page on the Lightning Design System, the unmanaged package has been deprecated due to SLDS being available in Salesforce without need for a static resource.  However, I'm having trouble grabbing SLDS icons for use in lightning components still.

Are the SLDS icons available without the need for a static resource?  If so, what's the path I should use for the SVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not natively available in lightning.  You will need to get a static resource.  There is a great explanation on why and the component workaround that you can use until it is supported.

[Lightning SVG Component Helper](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/#app)

Since posting, lightning components can now extend SLDS by using the force:slds markup.

[force:slds tag release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_lightning_slds.htm)

Lightning Icons can then be used by using the lightning:icon markup:

[lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm)